# How do I scrape specific data from a CSV file in Python?

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

Web scraping has been getting the best of me for the past few days. I know the very basics of it, but I've got no clue on how to scrape data properly. Here's the issue: I'm supposed to use a csv link (provided in the code below) to find out which of the Scandinavian countries (Denmark, Sweden and Norway) won the most gold medals in Curling, Skating, Skiing and Ice Hockey, all starting from year 2001. I made a very simple code as shown below (only for Curling though, I'll add the other sports later), but it doesn't return anything. I have no idea of what I'm missing, so I would truly appreciate any kind of input on this matter.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import operator
from collections import Counter
import re

url = "https://sites.google.com/site/dr2fundamentospython/arquivos/Winter_Olympics_Medals.csv"

csv = requests.get(url).text

lines = csv.splitlines()

for l in range(1, len(lines)):
  columns = lines[l].split(',')
  #print(columns)
  medalsSweden = 0
  medalsNorway = 0
  medalsDenmark = 0
  if columns[0] > '2001' and columns[4] == 'Curling' and columns[5] == 'NOR' and columns[7] == 'Gold':
    medalsNorway += medalsNorway + 1
    print(medalsNorway)
  else:
    if columns[0] > '2001' and columns[4] == 'Curling' and columns[5] == 'SWE' and columns[7] == 'Gold':
      medalsSweden += medalsSweden + 1
      print(medalsSweden)
    else:
      if columns[0] > '2001' and columns[4] == 'Curling' and columns[5] == 'DEN' and columns[7] == 'Gold':
        medalsDenmark += medalsDenmark + 1
        print(medalsDenmark)
```

Comment: You might want to look at the csv module to do the parsing. Also, you should use elif for your decision tree.  also since 3 of your conditions are the same in the decision tree, you might want to create an outer block with those 3 conditions, and inside just check the country.

Comment: If you have `pandas`, or can install it, reading a `csv` into a DataFrame is fast and easy.  The frame is like a table that you processing in many ways.

Comment: You are never converting your data to numbers, so the comparisons don't do what you think they do.

Comment: @hpaulj thank you so very much! never used pandas before, but found it truly helpful. All the others who commented as well, thank you all very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The columns you're checking don't match up. Looking at the columns in `lines`:

```
>>> lines[0]
'Year,City,Sport,Discipline,NOC,Event,Event gender,Medal'
```

The "sport" is `columns[2]` and country is `columns[4]`. (You're checking 4 & 5 instead.) Also, you were checking against "discipline" which is specific within the sport. For example, "Skiing" is the sport and "Alpine Skiing" is a discipline within it. So each `if` statement should be changed to:

```
... and columns[2] == 'Curling' and columns[4] == 'NOR' ...
```

---

Other improvements:

1. when dealing with numbers like 'Year', convert those to `int`s rather than doing string comparison:

   ```
   if int(columns[0]) > 2001 and ...
   ```

   In this case, you won't have an issue with it since they're 4-digit years and you're comparing with `'2001'`, a 4-digit string, so the string comparison works out.
2. Use the [CSV module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to parse CSV files
3. Re-structure your `if` statements so that they're not repetitive. Since you're only interested in `2001` onwards and `Gold` medals, it should be a top-level `if`. Others checks, if any, should be nested under it.

Comment: There are other changes and improvements to make, like those mentioned in the comments, but that would take away from your specific problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle that within `pandas.read_csv()` function easily:

```py
import pandas as pd


df = pd.read_csv(
    "https://sites.google.com/site/dr2fundamentospython/arquivos/Winter_Olympics_Medals.csv")

filt = (df['Year'] > 2001) & (df['Discipline'] == 'Curling') & (
    df['NOC'] == 'NOR') & (df['Medal'] == 'Gold')

print(df[filt])
```

```
      Year            City    Sport  ...    Event Event gender Medal
1972  2002  Salt Lake City  Curling  ...  curling            M  Gold        

[1 rows x 8 columns]
```